# Running .NET 4 program under lower .NET version

Tags: .net

Is it possible for a .NET 4 application to run when only for example .NET 3 framework is installed on the computer?

Comment: I really doubt that. You could ship and install .NET 4 with your setup or simply compile for .NET 2/3 only.

Comment: no, except when you bind the .net 4 library to your application using special tools like xenocode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it isn't possible.

They use different runtimes and you can't run an assembly targeting one runtime on a different runtime.

.NET 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 run on the 2.0 runtime.

.NET 4.0 has a new runtime.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Programs that depend on the 4 framework are not backwards compatible.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think that's possible.

However you can make an installer that can download the correct framework if it's not already installed. Visual Studio can create such an installer (add a Setup project to your solution).